# Exim doesn't work with dovecots LMTP router and virtual users

Tags: dovecot, exim

I'm trying to run a simple mail setup with dovecot and exim on a vanilla installation of Debian jessie. I followed the [instructions in the dovecot wiki](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LMTP/Exim) and configured my router accordingly:

```
local_user:
    debug_print = "R: local_user for $local_part@$domain"
    driver = accept
    domains = +local_domains
    check_local_user
    transport = dovecot_lmtp
    cannot_route_message = Unknown user
```

The problem now is that my users are stored with their full address in a passwd file, e.g. johnny@meyer.com and `check_local_user` tries to look up just the local part:

```
--------> local_user router <--------
local_part=johnny domain=meyer.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
meyer.com in "+local_domains"? yes (matched "+local_domains" - cached)
checking for local user
seeking password data for user "johnny": using cached result
getpwnam() returned NULL (user not found)
local_user router skipped: johnny is not a local user
```

If I delete the `check_local_user` line, everything will work fine, but I'm afraid that this part is there for a reason.

Am I doing something entirely wrong? Did I miss something obvious? Help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup authenticator properly. Also dovecot didn't use LMTP for delivery. More information can be provided if you show corresponding exim's config sections.